# Log read only at current date with error append to text file as output

Tags: scripting, vbscript, automation, batch-file

I Have below text on remote computers (a list of 50 servers) saved in e:\logs\action.log
This action.log will contain the a Date & time and every time a action performed will be tracked and appends the date & time..... and the next line will have the action 
associated like working, not working...

Sample action.log file text.....

```
[10/15/2012 09:33:56:248 qwe rtd] {some text will be there here}

this time it is working on the task and taken: 2.31 seconds

[10/15/2012 09:34:55:248 qwe rtd] {some text will be there here}

this time it is working on the task and taken: 3.31 seconds

[10/16/2012 09:33:56:248 qwe rtd] {some text will be there here}

this time it is working on the task and taken: 2.31 seconds

[10/16/2012 09:34:55:248 qwe rtd] {some text will be there here}

this time it is working on the task and taken: 3.31 seconds

[10/16/2012 09:34:55:248 qwe rtd] {you got error}
You got error as file missing..
```

The script I am looking for a script to read the action.log from the current date (todays date in the above example date is 10/16/2012). And if found any text called "you got error" or "error as file missing.." then output followed by server Name to a excel or a text file.

(the Basic criteria is to search on current date text only.... as past errors are not valid...)
Looking for some script from forum.... I am a new to scripting......

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
computer = CreateObject("WScript.Network").ComputerName

today = Right("0" & Month(Date), 2) & "/" & Right("0", Day(Date), 2) & "/" _
  & Year(Date)

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set in  = fso.OpenTextFile("action.log", 1)
Set out = fso.OpenTextFile("error.log", 2)

Do Until in.AtEndOfStream
  line = in.ReadLine
  If Left(line, Len(today)+1) = "[" & today Then
    ' line timestamped with today's date
    If InStr(line, "error") > 0 Then
      ' line contains "error"
      out.WriteLine line & vbTab & in.ReadLine & vbTab & computer
    End If
  End If
Loop

in.Close
out.Close
```