# Find the text in Vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I am looking for help to read a log file, where the log file has current date inside the log and I wanted to read from there all the line and look for a error to output the error with current date.

**My Sample Log file**

```
[10/12/2012 testing the app1
[10/13/2012 testing the app2
[10/14/2012 testing the app3
[10/15/2012 testing the app4
```

**My unfinished vbscript:**

```
Const ForReading = 1

Dim strSearchFor

strSearchFor = "currentdate in the log file"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("mylogfile.log", ForReading)

strLine = objTextFile.ReadLine

If log contains (inside mylogfile.log file the) current date then ' I am looking help to write the code here...

  Wscript.Echo "we found current date"

Else

  Wscript.Echo "We did not found current date"

End If
```

Looking for help in this... Thanks lot.... in advance...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926168/log-read-only-at-current-date-with-error-append-to-text-file-as-output

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930384/vbscript-text-file-search-a-line-with-multiple-strings

Answer (score 1):

[`InStr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wybb344c%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) will find a substring within a string

```
Const ForReading = 1

Dim strSearchFor
strSearchFor = "currentdate in the log file"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("mylogfile.log", ForReading)

do until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objTextFile.ReadLine()

    If InStr(strLine, strSearchFor) <> 0 then
        Wscript.Echo "we found current date"
    Else
        Wscript.Echo "We did not found current date"
    End If
loop
objTextFile.Close
```

Comment: The above script works... but need further modifications....code:///Const ForReading = 1

Dim strSearchFor, str1

strSearchFor = "currentdate in the log file"

str1 =erro1

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("mylogfile.log", ForReading)

do until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objTextFile.ReadLine()

    If InStr(strLine, strSearchFor) <> 0 then
        
find str1 in the log

    Else
        Wscript.Echo "We did not found current date"
    End If
loop
objTextFile.Close

Comment: Can you update your question with the additional requirements?

Answer (score 1):

This is the Powershell way (the question when I was writing was also tagged Powershell ...)

```
$log = get-content c:\path\mylogfile.log

$find = $log | select-string '10/15/2012' #the date you need to find

if ($find)
{
"we found current date"
}
Else
{
"We did not found current date"
}
```