# vbscript text file search a line with multiple strings

Tags: scripting, vbscript

Need small modification in the below vbscript...

```
Const ForReading = 1

Dim strSearchFor, set1, set2
strSearchFor = "10/17/2012"
set1= app1

set2 =app2

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("mylogfile.log", ForReading)

do until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objTextFile.ReadLine()

    If InStr(strLine, strSearchFor and set1 or set2) <> 0 then

Wscript.Echo "we found current date with app1 or current date with app2"
    Else
        Wscript.Echo "We did not found current date"
    End If
loop
objTextFile.Close
```

My actual mylogfile.log sample file has below in the text file.

```
working on 10/17/2012 starting something ending
closing on  started app1
working on 10/17/2012 starting something app1
working on 10/17/2012 starting something app2
closing on 10/17/2012 starting something ending
```

Thanks.. in advance for your valuable time ..

Answer (score 0):

`If InStr(strLine, strSearchFor and set1 or set2) <> 0 then`

It doesn't work this way. You can only search for one substring for each `Instr` call.

`If InStr(strLine, strSearchFor) <> 0 and (InStr(strLine, set1) or InStr(strLine, set2))   then`

Also, there's a problem with your loop, your script will echo for each line where you can't satisfy the condition. Use a flag or something similar to keep track whether the line was found and display the error at the end.