# VBscript output not writing correctly

Tags: scripting, vbscript

Hello Scripting Experts,

I have a log file on remote servers.. 
in remote servers `c:\vb\text.log`

I have included my remote systems in `list.Txt` like

```
server1
server2
```

below is the sample of log..

```
application working
[10/23/2012 working

[10/24/2012 nos appdown
error found you need to check this
```

Below is my Script.

```
Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set InFile = fso.OpenTextFile("list.Txt")
Set out = fso.CreateTextFile("error.log")

Const ForReading = 1
Do While Not (InFile.atEndOfStream)
  strComputer = InFile.ReadLine
  today = Date()
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  strFilePath = "\\" & strComputer & "\c$\vb\"

  Set InputFile = fso.OpenTextFile(strFilePath & "text.log", 1)
  Do While Not (InputFile.AtEndOfStream)
    strLine = InputFile.ReadLine

    If Left(line, Len(today)+1) = "[" & today Then
      ' line timestamped with today's date
      If InStr(line, "nos") > 0 Then
        ' line contains "error"
        out.WriteLine InStr & vbTab & strComputer
      End If
    End If
  Loop
  InputFile.close
Loop

out.Close
InFile.Close
```

Basically the above script should search from current date line only from the `text.log` file that is `[10/24/2012 nos appdown`. Then if found as "Nos" in the current date line.. then it should write to the `error.log` with computer Name.

In my case the output is not coming , however looks like it is searching for the string "Nos".

Kindly gail break me from this situation....

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/12926168/1630171.

Answer (score 3):

The bug is that you don't specify the explicit option. Like so,

```
option explicit
```

This will force VBScript to complain about nondeclared variables. By doing this, you easily can spot misspelled variable names. Delcare variables with dim statement, like so

```
dim Fso, out
```

Run the script again and see that you are using a non-existing and non-initialized variable in comparision:

```
strLine = InputFile.ReadLine ' Read stuff to strLine
If Left(line, Len(today)+1) = "[" & today Then ' ERROR. line has no value!
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your adaptation of my script:

- As was already pointed out by [vonPryz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13044177/1630171) this is the cause of the problem:

  > `strLine = InputFile.ReadLine`
  >    `If Left(line, Len(today)+1) = "[" & today Then`

  When you change a variable name from `file` to `strFile` you have to change *every* occurrence of that variable, not just the line where it's assigned.
- `out.WriteLine InStr & vbTab & strComputer`

  This line will also fail, because [`InStr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wybb344c%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) is a function and you don't call it with the correct number of arguments.
- `today = Date()`

  This should not be inside a loop unless you expect the date to change during the script run *and* need to have the current date in every loop cycle.
- `Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")`

  `fso` is instantiated at the beginning of the script. There's no need to re-instantiate it, especially not in each loop cycle. That's just a waste of resources.
- `Const ForReading = 1`

  There's no point in defining a constant when you're never using it.
- `Do While Not ...`

  Using `Do Until ...` would be easier to read and to understand.